# Is Sharepoint Server mandatory for Excel Services or Excel Web Access

Tags: sharepoint, excel, service

The Excel Services and Excel Web Access ship with Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007.
I'm wondering if Excel Services or any component of that technology could be used without running a Sharepoint Server.

Thanks in advance!
- phi

Comment: Update: at the time I raised this question I was looking into server-side excel calculations. Using the Excel client on the server is not a perfect solution, as the client might need user input, like message boxes. Excel Services allow the executions of excel sheets and use excel cells as input and output fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are only availble through SharePoint 2007 and don't exist as a standalone products. Microsoft is heavily pushing MOSS as the platform for most products they deliver online so I'd be very surprised to see any of these ship independantly.

Answer (score 2):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will do many of the things Excel Services does and also includes some functionality which you cannot get with Excel Services. SpreadsheetGear 2009 works with ASP.NET 2.0+. You can see some ASP.NET samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Comment: Thanks. In my case I was going to use a web service for remote method invocation and not a web client the user will directly interact with.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention any feature in specific but some of the functionality available in Excel Services is now available through [SkyDrive](http://www.skydrive.com).

The Excel Calculation Service protocol is also documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh633051(v=office.12).aspx in case you want to write your own protocol client.

Comment: Thanks. At that time I was asking this question I was looking for server-side excel calculations.